# Is there any way to just check if my monorepo doesn't contain circular dependencies between packages?

Tags: javascript, circular-dependency, lerna, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I have a mono repository for javascript projects based on lerna and yarn workspaces.

I'm aware of "--reject-cycles" argument, which I can pass along with the "bootstrap" command. But my goal is just to check if my monorepo doesn't contain circular dependencies between my packages. Simply lerna could analyze the only package.json of all my packages and nothing else.

The problem with bootstrap is that, doesn't work with yarn client. I can force to use npm client from the command line like this `lerna bootstrap --npm-client=npm --use-workspaces=false --reject-cycles`, but still just to check if I have circular dependencies this the approach seems to be overkill. Analyzing only package.json files could take only a few seconds, instead of a few minutes of performing full bootstrap.

Can lerna do what I need?

Or maybe somebody can recommend other tools which can do what I need?